# Error TS2304 with tsc but not with Webpack, for names in project d.ts files

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsc

### Problem

If I type `tsc main-test.ts --noEmit`, many `TS2304: Cannot find name TestInfo` error messages are displayed. The names it can't find are interfaces declared in `d.ts` files I have created in the project directory, eg `testGlobals.d.ts` below.

If I compile with Webpack and awesome-typescript-loader (`node_modules\.bin\webpack --config wtest.webpack.config.js`), these messages do not appear - the project compiles successfully.

Unfortunately, the same errors show up on Travis CI, even though the scripts that run on the CI server are compiled by webpack. How do I get rid of these errors?

### I have tried

Adding the project source directory to typeRoots in `tsconfig.json` in addition to `node_modules/@types`.

### Relevant files

wtest.webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');


var entryObj = {
    'test-script': path.join(__dirname, '/test/main-test.ts')
};
var manifestFile = '/test/manifest.json';
var outdir = '/dist/test';
var moduleRulesInclude = [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), path.join(__dirname, 'test')];
var devtool = 'cheap-source-map';

module.exports = {
    devtool: devtool,
    entry: entryObj,
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader'],
            include: moduleRulesInclude
        }]
    },
    // Workaround for `can't resolve module 'fs'` issue
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        module: false
    }
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "static"
  ]
}
```

testGlobals.d.ts

```
interface TestInfo {
    testName: string;
    url: string;
    title: string;
    author: string;
    chapterUrls: string[];
    parser: ParserReturner;
}
```